# How can I only focus in on an "input:text" without triggering its bound focus event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a input:text, I want to focus in on it, but I do not want to trigger it's binded event handler.
What can I do?

I guess:

1. get the handler
2. unbind it
3. focus
4. bind it

Comment: Why do you ask if you already know the the answer?

Comment: Thanks,i just find how to get the Event listener in jQuery.`$.cache`

Answer (score 0):

No binding or listeners. Just:

```
$('input:text:first').focus();
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/GSdSZ/

Comment: thanks,but it aready has `$('input:text:first').focus(function(){alert("focus");});` I need to not trigger the alert

Answer (score 0):

Under what conditions do you not want it to **not** trigger the handler?

Just check for that condition in the handler in an if statement and do not proceed with the rest of the function:

```
$('input:text:first').focus( function() {
    if(something you don't want...)    return;

   // else, keep going...
);
```